# Storing online high scores in open-source games

Tags: open-source

I'm wondering how this is typically done at a high level. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I understand, normally you could have some sort of validation. But if you have access to the source code, anyone could see how to send data to the server (or make your own server for that reason). Is there a viable solution for this?

Comment: so ur game is a single player game and u want to send the high scores to a server, ur concern being the validity of these claims ?

Comment: I don't have a game at the moment, just asking out of curiosity. But yeah, let's say I'm hosting a server and I want to see if a certain score is valid in a general way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easy or fool proof:

[Secure Online Highscore Lists for Non-Web Games](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999/)

Comment: There is some good info there, but not too focused on open source. It would not deal very well with someone disabling health loss, or increasing their speed, relatively minor adjustments to give ones self an edge.