# Using OpenID for simple leaderboard authentication in a video game leaderboard

Tags: c++, authentication, oauth, openid

I read this question ( [Secure Online Highscore Lists for Non-Web Games](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999/secure-online-highscore-lists-for-non-web-games) ) and came to the conclusion that I will not try to encrypt or secure the score itself.

However, I would like to add some kind of federated login (like OpenID) to my video game for sending scores but it seems to be best only for websites. Maybe OpenID + OAuth but it seems really best for access public APIs securely. Correct if I'm wrong on any of those points.

What would be the best solution considering that :

- I do not want to embed a browser in my C++ game (no WebKit etc.), for example Unity3D setup waits until you acquire a license from their website
- I do not want users to have another account to manage (they could use their Google, Twitter, etc. accounts)
- This would mainly be a mean to associate players and their scores, and possibly store their "display name" in the leaderboards

Thanks.