# Develop flash game that requires safe communication with a server

Tags: flash, security, actionscript, client-server

I want to develop a flash game (using ActionScript 3) that communicates with a java server to save statistics, scores and stuff like that from the player. But how can I create a save communication from the flash file to the server so that it is **not** possible to use some other tool to connect to the server and fake actions to cheat scores.

Is there any way to do this?

**My solution**:

> The game itself connects to a server that manages the whole game and all "calculations" and stuff like that are done at that server and every action the user does is sent to the server and everything the game does is controlled by the server.
>
> So the really only thing the flash file would do is display the graphics.

**BUT**: is there a better and safer way to do this? Or is this sulotion the best solution?

Because it would be a bit more easy to do if the flash file would also calculate what happens in the game and not only display the graphics.

Please tell me how you would solve this problem.

Comment: Can you not encode and decode it with a secret salt. Only your flash game and your server know how to decode it (with this secret salt). Users won't be able to cheat it that way.

Comment: But it would be possible to decompile the flash file and get the secret salt. Wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only way to make a fully secure game is to make all the game logic on the serverside (as you suggested) and validate every single action sent from the client. The client side role would be only to display graphics and do any calculation that doesn't affect the game mechanics. Remember Any code on the client side is hackable.

Comment: Yes. And by the way is flash actually decompileable?

Comment: sure, swf is very easily decompiled using decompile tools like sothink swf decompiler. Also there is even online tools to decompile online, like showmycode.com

Comment: Even with all the logic on the serverside, since the player's PC still control inputs, he can still cheat the game with normally impossible inputs (which is one of the many tricks of TAS players, btw). Moreover, by having all the logic server-side we introduce lag between input and display, which is perfectly acceptable for a multiplayer game, but more disputable for a singleplayer game with leaderboard.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, even if your server controls completelly what happens in your game, you still can't ensure that someone won't cheat.
As an example, anyone who truelly want it could decompile your game and create a "new client" that could autoaim on the ennemies.
That said, I'm recommanding that your read the following answers from previous questions :

[There is nothing you can do to prevent an attacker from forging high scores](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74841/2404734)

[Raising the bar for cheating above what a player would deem worth surmounting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/145450/2404734)

Comment: I have 2 notes regarding your answer: 1. it will be a hard work for someone to decompile and create a new client that auto aim. 2. you can still add server side validations as much as possible, for example validate how much emeny killed per seconds, how frequently they are shot and if the time between each 2 shots is the same through the level...etc and etc

Comment: decompiling-recompiling in AS3 is not that hard, given the number of tools available. And if adding server-side checks may detect cheating, people will find workaround for these checks. Moreover, the more checks you add, the more powerfull your server needs to be. We enter here in one of the battlezones of AAA games : developers and hackers constantly trying to 1up each other, without true winner, only temporary victories on both sides. Nowaday, anti-cheating strategies cannot block cheating, only to deter cheaters.