# How can I authenticate the source of a PHP post request?

Tags: php, post

I have a `PHP` script that connects to a `MySQL` database to post scores from a game I'm making in Unity3d to a leader board. It all works very well, but right now my script allows any post request with the right variables to add to the leader board. I would like for only post requests made from my Unity3D to be able to be authenticated.

I have looked into using `HTTP_REFERER`, but it is empty when posts are made from Unity. I was told that I can use "`static validation text`" with an `SSL` connection to act like a key to authenticate the post request. What would you all suggest? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999/secure-online-highscore-lists-for-non-web-games